# Evitar lineas en blanco al leer un .csv con opencsv en Java Android

Tags: java, android, csv, opencsv

Uso la librería opencsv para leer el contetino de un fichero .csv

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
String fileName = "file:///storage/sdcard1/maptest/cvs_test1.cvs";
final File file = new File(Uri.parse(fileName).getPath());

try {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), ',', '"', 1);

    //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
    String[] nextLine;
    try {
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                //Verifying the read data here
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Intento detectar si una linea es en blanco y así saltar a la siguiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado con:

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {    
    if (nextLine.length == 1 && nextLine[0].isEmpty()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Read csv: Skip Line Blank");
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No solo que sea diferente de nulo sino también que no sea vacío y que no sea igual al salto de línea

```
if (nextLine != null && !nextLine.isEmpty() && !nextLine.equals("\n")) {
                //Verifying the read data here
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));

            }
```